# rating button, one click to pass parameters and execute php

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm somehow stuck when I'm working on:

I want to pass a parameter to a php file and execute it when we rate something. php file is finished, but don't know how to code js part.

In detail,

1. user rates a passage, js gets the rating;
   ------ get parameters, store them in function Rate(), finished
2. when user submits it;
   ------ don't know how to check if the button is clicked, add DomListener in Rate()?
3. js calls the php file meanwhile passing the rating parameter to it;
   ------ php part finished
4. execute the php file without opening it in a new window.
   ----- don't know what to do.

HTML

```
<div>
  <form id="rateform" action="php/rate.php" enctype="text/form-data" method="POST"> 
    <input id="rating" type="text" />
    <input id="sbm" type="button" />
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
function Rate(){
  var rate = document.getElementById("rating").value;
  var sbm = document.getElementById("sbm");

  // don't know how to do...

  //if(sbm is clicked) {
  //   execute rate.php...
  //}
}
```

thx in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to do it, the simplest but not as pretty being just store whatever the user writes in a hidden field or keep it where it is and once user clicks submit pass all the data to the server?

Comment: @TeodorTalov exactly! but I don't know how to validate if the submit button is clicked..

Comment: @JonathandeM. sure, but very simple one, like I've posted above.

Comment: You should wrap your inputs into a form

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it in jQuery (better than dealing with an `XMLHttpRequest` object):

```
$('#sbm').click(function() {
    var rating = $('#rating').val();

    /* Send request to PHP script. */
    $.post('/url/to/script', { rating: rating }, function(resp) {
        console.log('Response:', resp);
    });
});
```

And your php script could be something like:

```
<?php echo 'Hey, I got this rating ' . $_POST['rating']; ?>
```

I'm not a PHP guy, though!